# What is required to create an offline TCP communication network?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, ethernet, network

I am designing an offline network consisting of a set of microcontrollers, with Ethernet capability, acting as servers, and a Raspberry Pi acting as a client for data collection.

The controllers are acting as servers and communicating with lab equipment, and sending data back to the Raspberry Pi via TCP. All are connected to an Ethernet switch.

My questions:

- Is this possible?
- Are the items listed all that would be required (besides code of course)?

I am not well versed in networking, so as much info as possible would be extremely helpful.

Comment: There's nothing saying that a LAN (which is basically what you're describing) has to be connected to a wider internet, so I'm pretty sure this is possible. The details of how to do it, however, are well outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Well then you and I are on equal footing sir lol

Comment: why do you ask? what problems do you expect? it is not different from a home network when you disconnect the router from the Internet

Comment: @Juraj What sparked this particular question is that I was testing an Arduino with keyestudio Ethernet shield directly connected to my laptops Ethernet port but it wouldn't find it, as opposed to when I connected it to my home router

Comment: @thunderbootyclap this is likely because the eth. shield was configured to use DHCP - a protocol by which nodes can be assigned IP and network settings froma central server (easier to administer than individual configs). your laptop had no such server running and as such the eth shield went unconfigured. The other possible option is that your laptop ethernet port is only set for DHCP and was unconfigured to talk to the eth shield.

Comment: You'll want to download wireshark - think of it as an oscilloscope for your network.

Comment: Microcontrollers "with ethernet capability" probably require line drivers, protection circuit and so on...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a switch (or a hub) is sufficient to create an Ethernet LAN. You will either need to assign IP addresses to each device manually, or run a DHCP server somewhere (perhaps on the Raspberry Pi). (Or use IPv6!)

Comment: Yes, there are IP ranges for this. You can also put a second network card in a PC to sniff your private network. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Or use link-local addressing, which is common enough to be a few clicks away on both Windows and Linux desktops, and is super-easy to administer.

Answer (score 2):

A much better design is when a more powerful device (RPI) is acting as a server, and less powerful devices (uCs) connect to it. Here is the reasoning:

- It is easy to DoS the device by creating many network connections. Say, a device has 40k of free RAM, and each connection takes 10k, then 4 connections is enough for the denial of service. Note the denial of service can be un-intentional!
- A device must implement authentication and authorisation mechanisms that are potentially vulnerable
- A network service code may be vulnerable
- If TLS is used for communication, the connection setup time could be large because of the slow CPU, leading to delays and bad user experience. Also TLS increases RAM usage per connection significantly

On the other hand, when a device acts as a client, these problems disappear:

- It is impossible to hack into the device directly because it does not expose any network endpoint
- A device does not care about authentication and authorisation - it is all handled on by the server
- The only entity a device should trust is a server
- No need to keep many network connections, cause a single secure connection to the cloud backend is enough for both management and data flows. This saves precious resources

A better design is when RPI runs DHCP, to auto-configure all uCs, and also runs a local server such as MQTT for low-overhead data transfer. This solution makes configuration easier: when new uCs are added/removed from the network, an RPI box does not need to be reconfigured. All clients (uCs) share the same configuration option: RPI address/port.